# How to get geometry of single element in viewer in autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

Determine the front and back side of doors or opening side of door using 3min js.
Following code is to get the mesh data of the selected element

```js
var fragmentproxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, fragIds);

console.log(fragmentproxy);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your questions? Please note the `Viewer` uses meshes, not the full geometry as in Revit desktop product.

Comment: Sir want to check door pull and push side area for clearance check. Is there any way to get 3d element details for its pull side area.

Comment: that information (side of a door) is not available on the 3D model on Viewer (it's just a closed door, visually), on the 2D view of the floor you can see it, but would be just a collection of lines (raw geometry)